# Cómo dibujar un corazón: (el algoritmo del corazón)

Tags: algoritmos

Acabo de ver la invitación de Stack Overflow en español para participar en [el concurso de Año Nuevo a las mejores preguntas y respuestas con la etiqueta algoritmos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3842/a%C3%B1o-nuevo-algor%C3%ADtmico-2019?cb=1). Y como que se acerca San Valentin me gustaría recoger algoritmos para dibujar corazones en CSS, en canvas, en SVG o en lo que os parezca.

#### Actualización

@Trauma comenta:

> Vale que el concurso está bien, un premio es un premio y tal, pero ... ¿ no debería ser por si misma una buena pregunta ? Porque así como está ... deja bastante que desear

Este comentario me hizo pensar que tendría que agregar algo de código a mi pregunta así que ahí voy:

El algoritmo que utilizo para dibujar un corazón es bastante versátil ya que lo puedo utilizar en CSS, en canvas y en SVG:

Primero estoy creando un array de puntos

```js
function corazon(r, paso) {
  let puntos = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < 2 * Math.PI; a += paso) {
    let p = {};
    p.x = cx + 16 * r * (Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a));
    p.y =
      cy -
      13 * r * Math.cos(a) +
      5 * r * Math.cos(2 * a) +
      2 * r * Math.cos(3 * a) +
      1 * r * Math.cos(4 * a);
    puntos.push(p);
  }
  return puntos;
}
```

Esta fórmula la encontré aquí [Draw a parametric heart-shaped curve in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/02/draw-parametric-heart-shaped-curve-c/)

La función function `corazon()` devuelve un array de puntos y voy a utilizar estos puntos para dibujar un corazón utilizando el canvas de HTML5, SVG y por último CSS y la propiedad `box-shadow`

#### En canvas

```js
// inicia el canvas
const c = document.getElementById("canv");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const cw = (c.width = 200);
const ch = (c.height = 200);
const cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2;
// define el grosor de línea  
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
// define el color de línea  
ctx.strokeStyle = "crimson";


// el algoritmo del corazón
function corazon(r, paso) {
  let puntos = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < 2 * Math.PI; a += paso) {
    let p = {};
    p.x = cx + 16 * r * (Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a));
    p.y =
      cy -
      13 * r * Math.cos(a) +
      5 * r * Math.cos(2 * a) +
      2 * r * Math.cos(3 * a) +
      1 * r * Math.cos(4 * a);
    puntos.push(p);
  }
  return puntos;
}



function dibujarCorazonEnCanvas() {
  // crea un array vacío para guardar los puntos
  let puntos = corazon(5, 0.05);
  // empieza el trazado
  ctx.beginPath();
  // mueve el puntero al primer punto del array
  ctx.moveTo(puntos[0].x, puntos[0].y);
  // dibuja el corazon 
  puntos.forEach(p => {
    ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
  });
  // cierra el trazado
  ctx.closePath();
  // dibuja el corazón
  ctx.stroke();
}


dibujarCorazonEnCanvas();
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```

#### En SVG

```js
// el centro del lienzo SVG
const cx = 100,cy = 100;

function corazon(r, paso) {
  let puntos = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < 2 * Math.PI; a += paso) {
    let p = {};
    p.x = cx + 16 * r * (Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a));
    p.y =
      cy -
      13 * r * Math.cos(a) +
      5 * r * Math.cos(2 * a) +
      2 * r * Math.cos(3 * a) +
      1 * r * Math.cos(4 * a);
    puntos.push(p);
  }
  return puntos;
}

function dibujarCorazonEnSVG() {
  // crea el array de los puntos
  let puntos = corazon(5, 0.05);
  // crea una cadena de texto para el atributo d de un trazado path
  let d = `M${puntos[0].x},${puntos[0].y}L`;

  puntos.forEach(p => {
    d += `${p.x},${p.y} `;
  });
  // establece el valor del atributo d 
  corazonSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
}

dibujarCorazonEnSVG();
```

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox = "0 0 200 200" width="200">
   <path id="corazonSVG" d="" />
</svg>
```

#### En CSS

Voy a utilizar el mismo algoritmo para dibujar un corazón utilizando `box-shadow`. Voy a utilizar JavaScript para calcular el valor de `box-shadow`.

```js
// crea una nueva hoja de estilos y la agrega al head
const s = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(s);

// el centro del div
const cx = 100,cy = 100;

// el algoritmo del corazón
function corazon(r, paso) {
  let puntos = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < 2 * Math.PI; a += paso) {
    let p = {};
    p.x = cx + 16 * r * (Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a) * Math.sin(a));
    p.y =
      cy -
      13 * r * Math.cos(a) +
      5 * r * Math.cos(2 * a) +
      2 * r * Math.cos(3 * a) +
      1 * r * Math.cos(4 * a);
    puntos.push(p);
  }
  return puntos;
}



function dibujarCorazonBoxShadow() {
  // crea el array de los puntos
  let puntos = corazon(5, 0.01);
  // un array par los fragmentos de reglas css para box-shadow
  let reglas = [];
  
  // para cada punto en el array
  puntos.forEach(p => {
    reglas.push(`${p.x}px ${p.y}px 0px 1px crimson`);
  });
  // construye el valor de box-shadow utilizando la propiedad textContent de la nueva hoja de estilo
  s.textContent = "div::before{box-shadow:";
  s.textContent += reglas.join();
  s.textContent += ";}";
}

dibujarCorazonBoxShadow();
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: - Este es un ejemplo de el algoritmo de corazon revisalo https://github.com/leios/simuleios/tree/master/heart

Comment: @Trauma He actualizado mi pregunta con un ejemplo. Tenía intención de agregarlo más tarde porque ahora tengo miedo que la gente piense que es una pregunta demasiado verbosa y no se animarán a contestarla. Espero que tengas una respuesta preparada para mi. Quiero ver tu corazón.

Comment: Ahora está mucho *mas mejor*, tienes mi +1. El JavaScript no es precisamente mi fuerte ... en fin, veremos que se puede hacer ❤❤❤

Comment: @Trauma Y mi +1? mi respuesta fué buena :D

Comment: Hay muy buenas respuestas, ¿por que ninguna ha sido aceptada?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En R hay varias formas que se pueden ver [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8082429/6836377), la que mas me convence es la que usa una ecuación parámetrica en particular para construir un "cardioide":

```
t <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1)
x <- 16*sin(t)^3
y <- 13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t)

plot(x, y, type="l")
polygon(x, y, col="hotpink")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicación:

- Con `t <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1)` generamos una secuencia de números que van de `0` a 2 veces `pi` en pasos de 0.1
- Aplicando sobre la secuencia, las formulas para `x` e `y` generamos estos valores que representarán los puntos externos de la forma
- Con `plot(x, y, type="l")` vamos dibujando líneas a partir de cada pareja de puntos `x`, `y`. Con `polygon(x, y, col="hotpink")` creamos un polígono con la forma dada por los puntos y lo rellenamos con color.

Answer (score 22):

Cómo dibujar un corazón explicado con primitivas, Saludos

```js
function clearDash(el) {
  var pathLength = el.getTotalLength() || el.node().getTotalLength();

  el.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', pathLength);
  el.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', pathLength);
}

clearDash(document.querySelector('.heart__circle1'));
clearDash(document.querySelector('.heart__circle2'));
clearDash(document.querySelector('.heart__heart'));

var timeline = anime.timeline({ autoplay: true, direction: 'normal', loop: true });

timeline
.add({
  targets: '.heart__box',
  strokeDashoffset: {
    value: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  opacity: {
    value: [1, 0.3],
    duration: 600,
    delay: 2600,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__circle1',
  strokeDashoffset: {
    value: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__circle2',
  strokeDashoffset: {
    value: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__circle1',
  translateX: {
    value: [0, 17.5],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 1600,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  opacity: {
    value: [1, 0.3],
    duration: 600,
    delay: 2600,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__circle2',
  translateY: {
    value: [0, -17.5],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 1600,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  opacity: {
    value: [1, 0.3],
    duration: 600,
    delay: 2600,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart',
  rotate: {
    value: [0, '-45deg'],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 2400,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__heart',
  strokeDashoffset: {
    value: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 3200,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
.add({
  targets: '.heart__heart2',
  opacity: {
    value: [0, 1],
    duration: 800,
    delay: 4000,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  },
  offset: 0
})
;
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.heart__heart2 {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<svg class="heart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <g stroke-width="2">
        <path class="heart__box" d="M31 31h38v38H31z" fill="none" stroke="#a9a9a9"/>
        <path class="heart__circle1" d="M69 50a19 19 0 0 1-19 19 19 19 0 0 1-19-19 19 19 0 0 1 19-19 19 19 0 0 1 19 19z" fill="none" stroke="#a9a9a9"/>
        <path class="heart__circle2" d="M69 50a19 19 0 0 1-19 19 19 19 0 0 1-19-19 19 19 0 0 1 19-19 19 19 0 0 1 19 19z" fill="none" stroke="#a9a9a9"/>
        <path class="heart__heart" d="M31.07 68.93V31.07s1.51-17.455 19.117-17.455c17.608 0 18.563 17.635 18.563 17.635s17.678 1 17.678 18.497c0 17.498-17.5 19.253-17.5 19.253z" stroke="#E52231" fill="none"/>
        <path class="heart__heart2" d="M31.07 68.93V31.07s1.51-17.455 19.117-17.455c17.608 0 18.563 17.635 18.563 17.635s17.678 1 17.678 18.497c0 17.498-17.5 19.253-17.5 19.253z" fill="#E52231"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.0/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="heart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12):

Otra opción es el path con **Bezier Curve** de **Ricardo Cabello** en uno de sus demos de como crear shapes con **THREE.js**.

Aquí un demo que hice usando esa figura agregándole algo de **extrude** para darle volúmen y multiplicándola:

```js
class LoveScene {
  constructor() {
    this.numHearts = 1000;
    this.colors = {
      red: 0xcc0000,
      choco: 0x3f2c1e
    }
    this.extrudeSettings = {
      amount: 8,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelSegments: 2,
      steps: 2,
      bevelSize: 20,
      bevelThickness: 20
    };

    this.mouseX = 0;
    this.mouseY = 0;
  
 this.isTweening = false;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.setup();
    this.makeLove();
    this.bindEvents();
    this.animate();
  }

  setup() {
    // renderer --------------
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    this.renderer.setSize(
      window.innerWidth,
      window.innerHeight
    );
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    // scene --------------
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(this.colors.red);
    this.scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(
      this.colors.red,
      0.002
    );

    // camera -------------------
    let fieldOfView = 60,
      aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      nearPlane = 1,
      farPlane = 1000;

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      fieldOfView,
      aspect,
      nearPlane,
      farPlane
    );
    this.camera.position.x = 2000;
    this.camera.position.y = 2000;
    this.camera.position.z = 2000;
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
  }

  appearScene() {
    this.renderer.domElement.style.opacity = 1;
  }

  makeLove() {
    this.makeHeartsAtmosphere();
    this.makeLights();
    this.makeTweenEntry();
  }

  makeHeartsAtmosphere() {
    let atmosphere = new THREE.Object3D();
    this.scene.add(atmosphere);

    let heartShape = new THREE.Shape();
    heartShape.moveTo(25, 25);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(25, 25, 20, 0, 0, 0);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(-30, 0, -30, 35, -30, 35);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(-30, 55, -10, 77, 25, 95);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(60, 77, 80, 55, 80, 35);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(80, 35, 80, 0, 50, 0);
    heartShape.bezierCurveTo(35, 0, 25, 25, 25, 25);

    let geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(
      heartShape,
      this.extrudeSettings
    );

    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: this.colors.choco,
      flatShading: true
    });

    // make atmosphere
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numHearts; i++) {

      let heart = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material
      );

      heart.position.set(
        (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000,
        (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000,
        (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000
      );

      heart.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);

      heart.rotation.x = Math.PI;
      heart.rotation.y = Math.random() * Math.PI;

      atmosphere.add(heart);

    }
  }

  makeLights() {
    let light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light1.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    this.scene.add(light1);

    let light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light2.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    this.scene.add(light2);

    let ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(this.colors.choco, 0.1);
    this.scene.add(ambient);
  }

  makeTweenEntry() {
  this.isTweening = true;
    this.appearScene();

    new TWEEN.Tween(this.camera.position)
      .to({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 100 }, 8000)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.Out)
      .delay(2000)
   .onComplete(() => this.isTweening = false)
      .start();
  }

  animate() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    TWEEN.update();
    // this.controls.update();

    this.camera.position.x += (this.mouseX - this.camera.position.x) * .01;
    this.camera.position.y += (- this.mouseY - this.camera.position.y) * .01;
    this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

  bindEvents() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove.bind(this), false);
  }

  onWindowResize() {
    let width = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight;

    this.renderer.setSize(
      width,
      height
    );

    this.camera.aspect = width / height;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  if (this.isTweening) return;
  
    this.mouseX = (event.clientX - (window.innerWidth / 2));
    this.mouseY = (event.clientY - (window.innerHeight / 2));
  }
}

new LoveScene();
```

```css
html, body { 
  margin: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

canvas { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: agrega el codigo y no uses imagenes

Comment: Una disculpa, eh puesto el código de mi ejemplo aquí.

Answer (score 11):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo mi aporte de un corazón con brillo en SVG jeje

```css
body{
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
  </radialGradient>
  <circle cx="53" cy="51" r="35" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="106" cy="51" r="35" fill="red" />
  <rect x=40 y="20" width="70" height="70" fill="red" transform="translate(30) rotate(45, 35, 35)"></rect>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="url(#grad)">
</svg>
```

no es un algoritmo como tal, solo una forma de dibujar un corazón con gradient.

https://codepen.io/memoadian/pen/vvMZOK

Comment: Gracias por el enlace. Puedes añadir el código aquí en SO?

Answer (score 8):

El viejo y querido Codepen

- https://codepen.io/stellina91/pen/grIHf
- https://codepen.io/kunalvarma05/pen/mJbBNY
- https://codepen.io/mindstorm/pen/aZZvKq
- https://codepen.io/tameraydin/pen/bAfws
- https://codepen.io/vivinantony/pen/gbENBB

Fuente de ejemplo:

- https://codepen.io/tameraydin/pen/bAfws

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS3 Heart</title>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<style>
    @keyframes beat {
0% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
50% {transform: scale(1.1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 70px #d5093c;}
100% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
}

#background {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: #ffa5a5;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%, #ffd3d3 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffa5a5), color-stop(100%,#ffd3d3));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
}
#chest {
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.heart {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%, #d5093c 40%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right 50%, left 50%, color-stop(0%,#F50A45), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
-webkit-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
-moz-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
}
.heart.center {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%, #d5093c 40%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#B80734), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
}
.heart.top {
z-index:3;
}
.side {
top:100px;
width:220px;
height:220px;
border-radius: 220px;
}
.center {
width:210px;
height:210px;
bottom:100px;
left:145px;
font-size:0;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
.left {
left:62px;
}
.right {
right:62px;
}
</style>

  
  <style>
  /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
  @keyframes beat {
0% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
50% {transform: scale(1.1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 70px #d5093c;}
100% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
}

#background {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: #ffa5a5;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%, #ffd3d3 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffa5a5), color-stop(100%,#ffd3d3));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
}
#chest {
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.heart {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%, #d5093c 40%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right 50%, left 50%, color-stop(0%,#F50A45), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
-webkit-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
-moz-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
}
.heart.center {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%, #d5093c 40%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#B80734), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
}
.heart.top {
z-index:3;
}
.side {
top:100px;
width:220px;
height:220px;
border-radius: 220px;
}
.center {
width:210px;
height:210px;
bottom:100px;
left:145px;
font-size:0;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
.left {
left:62px;
}
.right {
right:62px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="background"></div>
<div id="chest">
  <div class="heart left side top"></div>
  <div class="heart center">&hearts;</div>
  <div class="heart right side"></div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Agrego el código logo. Lo generé automáticamente usando una librería mía que convierte un path svg a comandos logo.

Esta es la imagen svg que utilicé, tal cual como la bajé de flaticon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 51.997 51.997" style="enable-background:new 0 0 51.997 51.997;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<path d="M51.911,16.242C51.152,7.888,45.239,1.827,37.839,1.827c-4.93,0-9.444,2.653-11.984,6.905
    c-2.517-4.307-6.846-6.906-11.697-6.906c-7.399,0-13.313,6.061-14.071,14.415c-0.06,0.369-0.306,2.311,0.442,5.478
    c1.078,4.568,3.568,8.723,7.199,12.013l18.115,16.439l18.426-16.438c3.631-3.291,6.121-7.445,7.199-12.014
    C52.216,18.553,51.97,16.611,51.911,16.242z M49.521,21.261c-0.984,4.172-3.265,7.973-6.59,10.985L25.855,47.481L9.072,32.25
    c-3.331-3.018-5.611-6.818-6.596-10.99c-0.708-2.997-0.417-4.69-0.416-4.701l0.015-0.101C2.725,9.139,7.806,3.826,14.158,3.826
    c4.687,0,8.813,2.88,10.771,7.515l0.921,2.183l0.921-2.183c1.927-4.564,6.271-7.514,11.069-7.514
    c6.351,0,11.433,5.313,12.096,12.727C49.938,16.57,50.229,18.264,49.521,21.261z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Esta es la misma imagen en png

[image: heart]

Este es el código en python que utilizo para convertir el path svg a logo. Genero dos scripts, el primero es para MSWLogo y el segundo para otros intérpretes

```
from SvgPath2Logo import SvgPath2Logo

path = """
    M51.911,16.242C51.152,7.888,45.239,1.827,37.839,1.827c-4.93,0-9.444,2.653-11.984,6.905
    c-2.517-4.307-6.846-6.906-11.697-6.906c-7.399,0-13.313,6.061-14.071,14.415c-0.06,0.369-0.306,2.311,0.442,5.478
    c1.078,4.568,3.568,8.723,7.199,12.013l18.115,16.439l18.426-16.438c3.631-3.291,6.121-7.445,7.199-12.014
    C52.216,18.553,51.97,16.611,51.911,16.242z M49.521,21.261c-0.984,4.172-3.265,7.973-6.59,10.985L25.855,47.481L9.072,32.25
    c-3.331-3.018-5.611-6.818-6.596-10.99c-0.708-2.997-0.417-4.69-0.416-4.701l0.015-0.101C2.725,9.139,7.806,3.826,14.158,3.826
    c4.687,0,8.813,2.88,10.771,7.515l0.921,2.183l0.921-2.183c1.927-4.564,6.271-7.514,11.069-7.514
    c6.351,0,11.433,5.313,12.096,12.727C49.938,16.57,50.229,18.264,49.521,21.261z
"""

s = SvgPath2Logo()

#comandos para mslogo
f = open('heart_mswlogo.lgo', 'wb')
f.write(s.toLogo(path, SvgPath2Logo.MSWLOGO,  2))
f.close()

#para otros interpretes de logo
f = open('heart_xlogo.lgo', 'wb')
f.write(s.toLogo(path, SvgPath2Logo.XLOGO,  2))
f.close()
```

Este es el script generado para MSWLogo

```
    ;Code generated for MSWLogo

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Basic Functions                                                       ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to dot_product :ux :uy :vx :vy
    output arccos (:ux*:vx+:uy*:vy)/((sqrt :ux*:ux+:uy*:uy)*(sqrt :vx*:vx+:vy*:vy))
end


;draws a cubic bezier curve from current point to (x, y)
;@param x1, y1 are the first control point
;@param x2, y2 are the second control point
;@param n is the number of points
to cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y :n

    make "dt (1.0/(:n-1))

    for [i 0 :n 1] [
        make "t :i*:dt

        ;calculating coefficients
        make "cx 3.0*(:x1-(first pos))
        make "bx 3.0*(:x2-:x1)-:cx
        make "ax :x-(first pos)-:cx-:bx

        make "cy 3.0*(:y1-(last pos))
        make "by 3.0*(:y2-:y1)-:cy
        make "ay :y-(last pos)-:cy-:by

        make "rx :ax*:t*:t*:t+:bx*:t*:t+:cx*:t+(first pos)
        make "ry :ay*:t*:t*:t+:by*:t*:t+:cy*:t+(last pos)

        ;goto new point
        setxy :rx :ry

        ;save the second control point
        make "lx1 :x2
        make "ly1 :y2
    ]
end


;draws an arc
;@param (cx, cy) is the center
;@param rx radius x
;@param ry radius y
;@param rt is the angle from the x-axis of the current coordinate system to the x-axis of the ellipse
;@param o which is the start angle of the elliptical arc prior to the stretch and rotate operations
;@param do is the difference between the initial and final angle
;see also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcParameterizationAlternatives
to draw_arc :cx :cy :rx :ry :rt :o :do

    ;make angle positive and less or equal than 360
    make "o (remainder (int :o) 360)

    if :o<0 [
        make "o :o+360
    ]

    ;set turning sense
    ifelse :do<0 [
        make "i -1
    ] [
        make "i 1
    ]

    ;draw arc
    for [a :o :o+:do :i] [
        ;calculate point
        make "px (cos :rt)*:rx*(cos :a)-(sin :rt)*:ry*(sin :a)+:cx
        make "py (sin :rt)*:rx*(cos :a)+(cos :rt)*:ry*(sin :a)+:cy

        ;goto the point
        setxy :px :py
    ]

end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;SVG Functions                                                         ;
;http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html                                   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


to absolute_moveto :x :y
  penup
  setxy :x :y
  pendown
  make "x0 (first pos)
  make "y0 (last pos)
end


to relative_moveto :x :y
  absolute_moveto :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to closepath
  setxy :x0 :y0
end


to absolute_horizontal_lineto :x
  setx :x
end


to relative_horizontal_lineto :x
  absolute_horizontal_lineto :x+(first pos)
end


to absolute_vertical_lineto :y
  sety :y
end


to relative_vertical_lineto :y
  absolute_vertical_lineto :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_lineto :x :y
  setxy :x :y
end


to relative_lineto :x :y
  absolute_lineto :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    ;n=1000 to ensure that the curve is smooth
    cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y 1000
end


to relative_cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier :x1+(first pos) :y1+(last pos) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_smooth_cubic_bezier :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x2 :y2 :x :y
end


to relative_smooth_cubic_bezier :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_quadratic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x :y
    ;quadratic bezier expressed as cubic bezier
    ;http://fontforge.github.io/bezier.html
    ;see also "Converting TrueType to PostScript"
    absolute_cubic_bezier (first pos)+(:x1-(first pos))*2/3 (last pos)+(:y1-(last pos))*2/3 :x+(:x1-:x)*2/3 :y+(:y1-:y)*2/3 :x :y
end


to relative_quadratic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier :x1+(first pos) :y1+(last pos) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_smooth_quadratic_bezier :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x :y
end


to relative_smooth_quadratic_bezier :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


;see also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcConversionEndpointToCenter
to absolute_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs :x2 :y2

    ;auxiliar calcs
    make "rt (remainder (int :rt) 360)
    make "x1 (first pos)
    make "y1 (last pos)
    make "tx1 (cos :rt)*(:x1-:x2)/2+(sin :rt)*(:y1-:y2)/2
    make "ty1 -(sin :rt)*(:x1-:x2)/2+(cos :rt)*(:y1-:y2)/2


    ;Correction of out-of-range rx and ry
    make "rx (abs :rx)
    make "ry (abs :ry)
    make "d (sqrt (:tx1*:tx1/(:rx*:rx)+:ty1*:ty1/(:ry*:ry)))
    make "rx :d*:rx
    make "ry :d*:ry

    ;auxiliar calcs    
    make "sq (sqrt abs (((:rx*:rx*:ry*:ry-:rx*:rx*:ty1*:ty1-:ry*:ry*:tx1*:tx1)/(:rx*:rx*:ty1*:ty1+:ry*:ry*:tx1*:tx1))))
    if :fa=:fs [
        make "sq -:sq
    ]    
    make "tcx :sq*:rx*:ty1/:ry
    make "tcy :sq*-:ry*:tx1/:rx

    ;calculating coefficients
    make "cx (cos :rt)*:tcx-(sin :rt)*:tcy+(:x1+:x2)/2
    make "cy (sin :rt)*:tcx+(cos :rt)*:tcy+(:y1+:y2)/2
    make "o dot_product 1 0 (:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (:ty1-:tcy)/:ry
    make "do (remainder (int (dot_product (:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (:ty1-:tcy)/:ry (-:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (-:ty1-:tcy)/:ry)) 360)

    ;draw
    draw_arc :cx :cy :rx :ry :rt -:o -:do
end


to relative_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs :x2 :y2 
    absolute_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs (first pos)+:x2 (last pos)+:y2
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Draw                                                                  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

absolute_moveto 103.822 -32.484
absolute_cubic_bezier 102.304 -15.776 90.478 -3.654 75.678 -3.654
relative_cubic_bezier -9.86 -0.0 -18.888 -5.306 -23.968 -13.81
relative_cubic_bezier -5.034 8.614 -13.692 13.812 -23.394 13.812
relative_cubic_bezier -14.798 -0.0 -26.626 -12.122 -28.142 -28.83
relative_cubic_bezier -0.12 -0.738 -0.612 -4.622 0.884 -10.956
relative_cubic_bezier 2.156 -9.136 7.136 -17.446 14.398 -24.026
relative_lineto 36.23 -32.878
relative_lineto 36.852 32.876
relative_cubic_bezier 7.262 6.582 12.242 14.89 14.398 24.028
absolute_cubic_bezier 104.432 -37.106 103.94 -33.222 103.822 -32.484
closepath
absolute_moveto 99.042 -42.522
relative_cubic_bezier -1.968 -8.344 -6.53 -15.946 -13.18 -21.97
absolute_lineto 51.71 -94.962
absolute_lineto 18.144 -64.5
relative_cubic_bezier -6.662 6.036 -11.222 13.636 -13.192 21.98
relative_cubic_bezier -1.416 5.994 -0.834 9.38 -0.832 9.402
relative_lineto 0.03 0.202
absolute_cubic_bezier 5.45 -18.278 15.612 -7.652 28.316 -7.652
relative_cubic_bezier 9.374 -0.0 17.626 -5.76 21.542 -15.03
relative_lineto 1.842 -4.366
relative_lineto 1.842 4.366
relative_cubic_bezier 3.854 9.128 12.542 15.028 22.138 15.028
relative_cubic_bezier 12.702 -0.0 22.866 -10.626 24.192 -25.454
absolute_cubic_bezier 99.876 -33.14 100.458 -36.528 99.042 -42.522
closepath
```

Este es el código generado para otros intérpretes

```
    ;Code generated for Generic logo interpreters
;You can run it in http://www.calormen.com/jslogo or https://turtleacademy.com.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Basic Functions                                                       ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


to arcsin :a
  if :a=-1 [
    output -90
  ]
  if :a=1 [
    output 90
  ]
  output arctan :a/(sqrt 1-:a^2)
end


to arccos :a
  if :a=0 [
    output 90
  ]

  ifelse :a<0 [
      output 180+(arctan (sqrt 1-:a^2)/:a)
  ] [
      output arctan (sqrt 1-:a^2)/:a    
  ]
end


to dot_product :ux :uy :vx :vy
    output arccos (:ux*:vx+:uy*:vy)/((sqrt :ux^2+:uy^2)*(sqrt :vx^2+:vy^2))
end


;draws a cubic bezier curve from current point to (x, y)
;@param x1, y1 are the first control point
;@param x2, y2 are the second control point
;@param n is the number of points
to cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y :n

    make "dt (1.0/(:n-1))

    for [i 0 :n 1] [
        make "t :i*:dt

        ;calculating coefficients
        make "cx 3.0*(:x1-(first pos))
        make "bx 3.0*(:x2-:x1)-:cx
        make "ax :x-(first pos)-:cx-:bx

        make "cy 3.0*(:y1-(last pos))
        make "by 3.0*(:y2-:y1)-:cy
        make "ay :y-(last pos)-:cy-:by

        make "rx :ax*:t^3+:bx*:t^2+:cx*:t+(first pos)
        make "ry :ay*:t^3+:by*:t^2+:cy*:t+(last pos)

        ;goto new point
        setxy :rx :ry

        ;save the second control point
        make "lx1 :x2
        make "ly1 :y2
    ]
end


;draws an arc
;@param (cx, cy) is the center
;@param rx radius x
;@param ry radius y
;@param rt is the angle from the x-axis of the current coordinate system to the x-axis of the ellipse
;@param o which is the start angle of the elliptical arc prior to the stretch and rotate operations
;@param do is the difference between the initial and final angle
;see also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcParameterizationAlternatives
to draw_arc :cx :cy :rx :ry :rt :o :do

    ;make angle positive and less or equal than 360
    make "o :o%360

    if :o<0 [
        make "o :o+360
    ]

    ;set turning sense
    ifelse :do<0 [
        make "i -1
    ] [
        make "i 1
    ]

    ;draw arc
    for [a :o :o+:do :i] [
        ;calculate point
        make "px (cos :rt)*:rx*(cos :a)-(sin :rt)*:ry*(sin :a)+:cx
        make "py (sin :rt)*:rx*(cos :a)+(cos :rt)*:ry*(sin :a)+:cy

        ;goto the point
        setxy :px :py
    ]

end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;SVG Functions                                                         ;
;http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html                                   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


to absolute_moveto :x :y
  penup
  setxy :x :y
  pendown
  make "x0 (first pos)
  make "y0 (last pos)
end


to relative_moveto :x :y
  absolute_moveto :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to closepath
  setxy :x0 :y0
end


to absolute_horizontal_lineto :x
  setx :x
end


to relative_horizontal_lineto :x
  absolute_horizontal_lineto :x+(first pos)
end


to absolute_vertical_lineto :y
  sety :y
end


to relative_vertical_lineto :y
  absolute_vertical_lineto :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_lineto :x :y
  setxy :x :y
end


to relative_lineto :x :y
  absolute_lineto :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    ;n=1000 to ensure that the curve is smooth
    cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y 1000
end


to relative_cubic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier :x1+(first pos) :y1+(last pos) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_smooth_cubic_bezier :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x2 :y2 :x :y
end


to relative_smooth_cubic_bezier :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_cubic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_quadratic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x :y
    ;quadratic bezier expressed as cubic bezier
    ;http://fontforge.github.io/bezier.html
    ;see also "Converting TrueType to PostScript"
    absolute_cubic_bezier (first pos)+(:x1-(first pos))*2/3 (last pos)+(:y1-(last pos))*2/3 :x+(:x1-:x)*2/3 :y+(:y1-:y)*2/3 :x :y
end


to relative_quadratic_bezier :x1 :y1 :x2 :y2 :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier :x1+(first pos) :y1+(last pos) :x2+(first pos) :y2+(last pos) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


to absolute_smooth_quadratic_bezier :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x :y
end


to relative_smooth_quadratic_bezier :x :y
    absolute_quadratic_bezier (2*(first pos)-(:lx1)) (2*(last pos)-(:ly1)) :x+(first pos) :y+(last pos)
end


;see also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcConversionEndpointToCenter
to absolute_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs :x2 :y2


    ;auxiliar calcs
    make "rt :rt%360
    make "x1 (first pos)
    make "y1 (last pos)
    make "tx1 (cos :rt)*(:x1-:x2)/2+(sin :rt)*(:y1-:y2)/2
    make "ty1 -(sin :rt)*(:x1-:x2)/2+(cos :rt)*(:y1-:y2)/2


    ;Correction of out-of-range rx and ry
    make "rx (abs :rx)
    make "ry (abs :ry)
    make "d (sqrt (:tx1^2/:rx^2+:ty1^2/:ry^2))
    make "rx :d*:rx
    make "ry :d*:ry

    ;auxiliar calcs    
    make "sq (sqrt abs (((:rx^2*:ry^2-:rx^2*:ty1^2-:ry^2*:tx1^2)/(:rx^2*:ty1^2+:ry^2*:tx1^2))))
    if :fa=:fs [
        make "sq -:sq
    ]    
    make "tcx :sq*:rx*:ty1/:ry
    make "tcy :sq*-:ry*:tx1/:rx

    ;calculating coefficients
    make "cx (cos :rt)*:tcx-(sin :rt)*:tcy+(:x1+:x2)/2
    make "cy (sin :rt)*:tcx+(cos :rt)*:tcy+(:y1+:y2)/2
    make "o dot_product 1 0 (:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (:ty1-:tcy)/:ry
    make "do (dot_product (:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (:ty1-:tcy)/:ry (-:tx1-:tcx)/:rx (-:ty1-:tcy)/:ry)%360

    ;draw
    draw_arc :cx :cy :rx :ry :rt -:o -:do
end


to relative_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs :x2 :y2 
    absolute_arc :rx :ry :rt :fa :fs (first pos)+:x2 (last pos)+:y2
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;Draw                                                                  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

absolute_moveto 103.822 -32.484
absolute_cubic_bezier 102.304 -15.776 90.478 -3.654 75.678 -3.654
relative_cubic_bezier -9.86 -0.0 -18.888 -5.306 -23.968 -13.81
relative_cubic_bezier -5.034 8.614 -13.692 13.812 -23.394 13.812
relative_cubic_bezier -14.798 -0.0 -26.626 -12.122 -28.142 -28.83
relative_cubic_bezier -0.12 -0.738 -0.612 -4.622 0.884 -10.956
relative_cubic_bezier 2.156 -9.136 7.136 -17.446 14.398 -24.026
relative_lineto 36.23 -32.878
relative_lineto 36.852 32.876
relative_cubic_bezier 7.262 6.582 12.242 14.89 14.398 24.028
absolute_cubic_bezier 104.432 -37.106 103.94 -33.222 103.822 -32.484
closepath
absolute_moveto 99.042 -42.522
relative_cubic_bezier -1.968 -8.344 -6.53 -15.946 -13.18 -21.97
absolute_lineto 51.71 -94.962
absolute_lineto 18.144 -64.5
relative_cubic_bezier -6.662 6.036 -11.222 13.636 -13.192 21.98
relative_cubic_bezier -1.416 5.994 -0.834 9.38 -0.832 9.402
relative_lineto 0.03 0.202
absolute_cubic_bezier 5.45 -18.278 15.612 -7.652 28.316 -7.652
relative_cubic_bezier 9.374 -0.0 17.626 -5.76 21.542 -15.03
relative_lineto 1.842 -4.366
relative_lineto 1.842 4.366
relative_cubic_bezier 3.854 9.128 12.542 15.028 22.138 15.028
relative_cubic_bezier 12.702 -0.0 22.866 -10.626 24.192 -25.454
absolute_cubic_bezier 99.876 -33.14 100.458 -36.528 99.042 -42.522
closepath
```

En la primera parte de los scripts se incluyen funciones generales y al final se incluyen los comandos que realizan el dibujo en sí

Este es el resultado de ejecutar el segundo script en https://www.calormen.com/jslogo/

[image: interprete logo online]

Acá explico como funciona la biblioteca 
http://lopezezequiel.com/svgpath2logo/

Acá esta el repo 
https://github.com/lopezezequiel/SvgPath2Logo

Answer (score 7):

**Corazon en HTML CSS**

corazon que late en mouse hover !

A la clase `Corazon` se le da una medida teniendo en cuenta el siguiente dato :

```
width = 100%
height = 85%
```

el margen es a eleccion, en este caso lo use mas que nada para centrarlo.

a este punto creamos 2 rectangulos, aprovechando el `:before` y el `:after`, a estos les agregamos el radius a los angulos superiores, que tienen que tener un radius que tiene que ser la mitad del width (no funciona con el 50%).

el width de los rectangulos es la mitad del `width` de la clase corazon. mientras al `height` se le saca, mas o menos un 5% de la altura de la clase.

despues se rotean gracias al `transform: rotate()` nuestros `before` y `after` 
uno de `45deg` y el otro de `-45deg`. recordar que el `after`, que en este caso esta girado de `-45deg`, tiene que tener la propriedad `left` con un valor equivalente a su width.

Le agregamos tambien el `box-shadow` para hacer mas atractiva nuestra figura, aca es a gusto proprio.

y le agregamos una animacion en `hover` que aumente su medida, en los porcentajes : `0%   20%   40%   y 100%`.

```css
.corazon{
    position: relative;
    width : 400px;
    height: 340px;
    margin: 5% auto;
}
.corazon:before,
.corazon:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
.corazon:before{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  box-shadow: 5px -3px 10px;
}
.corazon:after{
  left: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 6px 8px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.corazon:hover{
  animation: corazon 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes corazon{
   0%{transform: scale(1,1)}
   20%{transform: scale(1.1,1.1)}
   40%{transform: scale(1.3,1.3)}
   100%{transform: scale(1,1)}
}
```

```html
<div class="corazon"></div>
```

espero que les guste !!

Answer (score 6):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una forma de dibujar un corazón via css:

```css
.corazon{
        position: relative;
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
        width: 125px;
        margin: 40px auto;
        animation: corazon 1s infinite;
    }
    .corazon:before{
        content:'';
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff4f81, #FF5F81 21%, #ff4f81);
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50% / 50% 0 50% 50%;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .corazon:after{
        content:'';
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff4f81, #FF5F81 31%, #ff4f81);
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50% / 50% 0 50% 50%;
        transform: rotate(145deg);
        clip-path: polygon(0 -100%, 0 100%, 45% 100%, 100% 0);
        position: absolute;
        left: 24px;
    }

    @keyframes corazon {
        0% {transform: rotate(-5deg);}
        50% {transform: rotate(0) scale(1.05);}
        1000% {transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    }
```

```html
<div class="corazon"></div>
```

```
https://codepen.io/maquetadorweb/pen/pqXeqo
```

Comment: responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: se te agradece la intención, pero es necesario que le des editar a esta publicación y añadas todo lo relevante aquí si es tu código y si es de un tercero dejes los créditos correspondientes

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Un algoritmo para utilizar en SVG y Canvas

Este es un algoritmo que utiliza [Ana Tudor](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/KVOyNR) en algunos pens. He adaptado este algoritmo para utilizarlo en SVG y en canvas:

```js
function corazon(r){
// una función que devuelve un objeto que puede ser utilizado para dibujar un corazón utilixando curvas Bézier (cubicas y cuadraticas)
// el centro del corazón se encuentra en un punto cuyas coordenadas son x=0, y=0
  let o = {}
  o.ymm =-.225*r;
 o.yum =-.625*r;
 o.xo  = .625*r;
 o.yuo =-.625*r;
 o.ymo =-.2*r;
 o.ylo = .25*r;
 o.ylm = .5625*r;
  return o;
} 

// SVG

function corazonSVG(r){
// una función que dibuja un corazón 
// devuelve el valor del atributo d para un elemento path
   let o = corazon(r);
   let d = `M0,${o.ymm} 
           C0,${o.yum} ${o.xo},${o.yuo} ${o.xo},${o.ymo} 
           Q${o.xo},${o.ylo} 0,${o.ylm}
           Q${-o.xo},${o.ylo} ${-o.xo},${o.ymo}
           C${-o.xo},${o.yuo}  0,${o.yum} 0,${o.ymm}`;
   return d; 
}

// establece el valor del atributo d del path elCorazonSVG
elCorazonSVG.setAttributeNS(null,"d", corazonSVG(100))


// CANVAS

let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cw = canvas.width = 200,cx = cw/2;
let ch = canvas.height = 200,cy = ch/2;

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "crimson"

ctx.translate(cx,cy)
corazonCanvas(100,ctx)

function corazonCanvas(r,ctx){
  // una función que dibuja un corazón en canvas
  let o = corazon(r);
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(0,o.ymm);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,o.yum,o.xo,o.yuo,o.xo,o.ymo);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(o.xo,o.ylo,0,o.ylm);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(-o.xo,o.ylo,-o.xo,o.ymo);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(-o.xo,o.yuo,0,o.yum,0,o.ymm);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
svg,canvas{border:1px solid; width:200px}
path{fill:none; stroke:crimson; stroke-width:3}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
<path id="elCorazonSVG" />    
</svg>

<canvas></canvas>
```

#### 2. Otra manera de dibujar un corazón en CSS

En este caso utilizo dos elementos `div` con bordes redondeados. Esto crea dos óvalos que estoy girando hacia la derecha y hacia la izquierda. Puede cambiar el valor de la variable `--h` para generar corazones de varios tamaños.

```css
.corazon{
    --h: 70;/*cambia esto para cambiar el tamaño del corazón*/
    /* este es el tamaño del corazón en vh. Si prefieres que sea en píxeles cambia 1vh por 1px */

 width:calc(var(--h) * .9 * 1vh);
 height:calc(var(--h) * 1vh);
 top:0;bottom:0;
 left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
 }

.corazon div{
 background:#ff0000;
 width:calc((2*var(--h) / 3) * 1vh);
 height:calc(var(--h) * 1vh);
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 border-radius:50%;
 }

.izquierda {
  left:0;
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
}

.derecha{
  right:0;
  transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="corazon">
 <div class="izquierda"></div>
 <div class="derecha"></div>
</div>
```